# Configure Memcache with Castle ActiveRecord?

Tags: nhibernate, castle-activerecord

Anyone know how to configure an ActiveRecord/nhibernate application to use Memcache as the 2nd level cache?

Comment: If you have specific issues with this setup I recommend creating a specific question with all relevant details... general questions will always get general answers. Also please note that StackOverflow is not a typical mailing list, it's a question/answer site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the [ActiveRecord docs on second level cache configuration](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/documentation/trunk/advanced/secondLevelCache.html). Then, for specific information about Memcached, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721964/nhibernate-and-memcached-tutorial-example).

You'll end up with a config similar to this:

```
<activerecord>      
  <config>
    <add key="connection.driver_class" value="NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver" />
    <add key="dialect" value="NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect" />
    <add key="connection.provider" value="NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider" />
    <add key="connection.connection_string" value="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=SSPI" />    
    <add key="cache.provider_class" value="NHibernate.Caches.MemCache.MemCacheProvider, NHibernate.Caches.MemCache"/>
    <add key="cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
    <add key="cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
  </config>      
</activerecord>
```