# Configure Membase server with nHibernate and ActiveRecord

Tags: nhibernate, activerecord, membase

I'm using nHibernate 3.1 and ActiveRecord 3.0 and I'm trying to get Membase server to work following this article: http://blog.ovesens.net/2011/02/nhibernate-membase-caching-provider/

but I'm not sure how to configure ActiveRecord with it?

Thanks in advance.
Aaron.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Configure Memcache with Castle ActiveRecord?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407566/configure-memcache-with-castle-activerecord)

Answer (score 0):

The article discusses using Membase as a cache, not as a system to query from ActiveRecord.  The idea here would be that Membase is a highly-available cache for the system.